# NSStatusItem's menu are not shown in Full Screen Model for the Mac os 10.13.1

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

all:

I have added one NSStatusItem in the status bar for my test app,  and it works well in Mac ox 10.12, not only normal model, but also full screen model. When i switch to Mac os 10.13, it is failed to show the menu in the full screen model.

```html
self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
        self.statusItem.highlightMode = YES;
        self.statusItem.menu = self.dummyMenu;
        [self.statusItem.menu setDelegate:self];
        self.statusItem.image = image;
```

does anyone has any idea?
[The pop up menu, in full screen model, it will not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQD86.png)

Comment: It's a bug of Mac os 10.13?  Does anyone know?

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: God blees me~~~ ^_^

Comment: no one has any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I also have encountered the same issue and found the solution that

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory];
```

shows the menu, though hides its main menu and dock.
I hope this helps.